# owlim library use of configuration file

Tags: owl, sesame

I am trying to work with the [owlim library](http://www.ontotext.com/owlim) to edit the owl ontology file. I started with the 'getting-started' example code included in the owl library. When I use the library with this example code it all works perfect. It uses de owlim.ttl file to configure the repository and this contains the path to this repository too:

(owlim.ttl:)

```
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>.
@prefix rep: <http://www.openrdf.org/config/repository#>.
@prefix sr: <http://www.openrdf.org/config/repository/sail#>.
@prefix sail: <http://www.openrdf.org/config/sail#>.
@prefix owlim: <http://www.ontotext.com/trree/owlim#>.

[] a rep:Repository ;
   rep:repositoryID "owlim" ;
   rdfs:label "OWLIM Getting Started" ;
   rep:repositoryImpl [
     rep:repositoryType "openrdf:SailRepository" ;
     sr:sailImpl [
       owlim:ruleset "owl-horst-optimized" ;
       owlim:entity-index-size "5000000" ;
       owlim:cache-memory "180m" ; 
       sail:sailType "swiftowlim:Sail" ; 
       owlim:noPersist "false" ;
       owlim:storage-folder "storage" ;
       owlim:base-URL "http://example.org/owlim#" ;
       owlim:repository-type "in-memory-repository" ;
       owlim:imports "./sesame/example.rdfs" ;
       owlim:defaultNS "http://example.org/owlim#" ;
      ]
   ].
```

On the [documentation site](http://owlim.ontotext.com/display/OWLIMv40/OWLIM-Lite+Configuration) they explicitly say that:

`'With the example set up, OWLIM-Lite loads two ontologies at start up as specified by the imports parameter in the repository configuration file, i.e. owlim.ttl'`,

but when I change that path to another file, I still get the same output like before. Even when I try to change something in this example.rdfs repository, the results of the queries don't change.
Does anybody know what the problem could be? Is the path specified somewhere else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The imports configuration parameter is used for once only initialisation of the repository with read-only schema. Once created, these statements can not be changed, so when you later modify this parameter and restart using an old repository, you will not see any differences.

In order to use a different imported schema, you must create a new repository.

Comment: I changed the statements when the application wasn't running. When I recompile and restart the application, it think it reloads the repository? (i.e. when the application is stopped, the repository in the memory is gone and when the application restarts, the repository has be to loaded in again)

Comment: OWLIM-Lite serialises the contents of a repository on shutdown and reloads this on start up. Once the repository is created, your imported ontology will not be loaded again irrespective of whether you change the ontology file or whether OWLIM is running when you do so.
The intention with this parameter is to do once-only loading of schema that will never change. If you need to change this ontology/schema, then you must recreate your repository and reload any other data. Just because OWLIM is not running does not mean that the repository does not exist.
I hope this helps, barry

Comment: Thank you for this information Barry. I see what the problem is, but I  don't know for sure what the solution could be: do I have to explicitly delete the repository of the previous session when the loader initializes? I tried to manually delete the example.rdfs and replaced it with another repository, but like you said this has no effect.

Comment: @Jaspack, I think the solution actually is that you shouldn't rely on the owl:imports paramater to create your repository. Instead, just load the data you want to load (either programmatically or via the Workbench application), trust OWLIM's own persistence mechanism to keep that data safe, and delete/modify when you want to update it.